# Retrieve a list of all users ldap

Tags: php, ldap, symfony-1.4, ldap-client

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all users that exists on ldap, in order to create an autocomplete box in jquery. However, I do not manage to get it. I can connect and bind to the ldap server, then I try and use `ldap_list()`. I leave a blank in the filter not to filter anything and get the entire list. However `ldap_list()` sets a warning (`Search: Can't contact LDAP server`) and returns `FALSE`, which makes everything go wrong since it's a boolean and it's not what's expected (`Warning: ldap_get_entries() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given`). Here's a sample of my code:

```
$identifier = ldap_connect(sfConfig::get('sf_ldap_host'));
if (!ldap_bind($identifier,
    sfConfig::get('sf_ldap_generic_user').sfConfig::get('sf_ldap_usr_domain'),
    sfConfig::get('sf_ldap_generic_password')))
{
    throw new sfException('could not bind to the Active Directory');
}
$list = ldap_list($identifier, sfConfig::get('sf_ldap_dn'), '', array('mail'));
$list_user = ldap_get_entries($identifier, $list);
```

Comment: Thanks for editing, can't quite get how to indent

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the server
2. Change the authorization state by transmitting a BIND request with a DN that has sufficient access to search all parts of the DIT
3. If the BIND was successful, retrieve a list of all `namingContexts` from the Root DSE
4. For each namingContext, transmit a search request using a base object of the namingContext, a scope of `sub`, a filter of `(&)` or `(objectClass=*)`, articulate a list of the attributes desired. For just users, use a filter `(objectClass=<object class in each user object>)`, for example, `(objectClass=person)`
5. Each search result in the response from the server contains objects that matched the search parameters

The authorization state set by the BIND must permit access, and be allowed to return as many objects as requested. Servers are permitted to restrict the number of entries returned to a client, and also to restrict the number of seconds spent in evaluating an LDAP operation, in this case, a search.

Note that a properly configured server may not permit trawling of the directory due to the load this places on the server (which will affect other clients). Consider informing the directory server administrators that your client plans to list all users.

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: The Root DSE](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html)

Comment: Hey @Terry Gardner, i m not able to get all users by using (objectClass=*), i m getting data by using  ("dc=example,dc=com") ,but i want all user data, can you suggest me any solution for that.